# Keras Neural Networks and SKlearn SVM.SVC

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras

Lately I was on a Data Science meetup in my city, there was a talk about connecting Neural Networks with SVM. Unfortunately presenter had to quit right after presentation, so I wasn't able to ask some questions.

I was wondering how is that possible ? He was talking about using neural networks for his classification, and later on, he was using SVM classifier to improve his accuracy and precision by about 10%.

I am using Keras for Neural Networks and SKlearn for the rest of ML.

Comment: One could always use [ensembling/stacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning) where some final predictor is a SVM. A probably more interesting approach is replacing the final layer with a SVM-layer (and train jointly) as described in [this paper](http://deeplearning.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/dlsvm.pdf)

Comment: Replacing last layers sounds like a "harsh" approach. I was thinking about taking the last layer of a neural network, and then try to process it in SVM.

Comment: Replacing these layers won't work for every task, but will add something to some.It's a nice approach of adding some more theoretically-justified method to some part of your nonlinear predictor. The difference to your approach is this:If some max-marging based approach is added as layers, *it's learned jointly!* This means, that with a bit of luck and good architecture, the NN can act as a nonlinear preprocessor tuned for the max-marging classif. by the last layer. With your approach, you will learn both models without any knowledge about the SVM within the NN. This is in general less powerful

Comment: If you want to pursue your svm-after-nn approach, then try it. I don't see many problems there as keras probably supports the sklearn interface (fit, maybe fit_transform and co.). This would mean you could build some pipeline. But as these are not really connected like explained above you will need a lot of tuning in regards to architecture, regulization and co. Even if the NN as first part is very powerful as classification-unit itself, this does not mean, that these predictions are good inputs for further svm-processing (some loosely connected keyword (opposite direction): *whitening*).

Comment: Ok, so I would like to try your approach, have you ever tried to implement such a solution before ? I get the main idea, but at this moment it is hard for me to imagine how the implementation should look like.

Comment: I did not try it but you got a complete scientific paper explaining the concept. If you are familiar with your tools, it won't be hard. But i expect you would need a lot of custom stuff implemented in theano for usage within keras. I'm not sure why or what for you want to try this. Maybe it will be wasted work for you (except for learning new ideas and programming-related stuff). It's very hard to say if this is approach is good for some task X a-priori.

Answer (score 6):

This is completely possible and actually quite common. You just select the output of a layer of the neural network and use that as a feature vector to train a SVM. Generally one normalizes the feature vectors as well.

Features learned by (Convolutional) Neural Networks are powerful enough that they generalize to different kinds of objects and even completely different images. For examples see the paper [CNN Features off-the-shelf: an Astounding Baseline for Recognition](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.6382).

About implementation, you just have to train a neural network, then select one of the layers (usually the ones right before the fully connected layers or the first fully connected one), run the neural network on your dataset, store all the feature vectors, then train an SVM with a different library (e.g sklearn).